# Restful WCF and Basic Authentication via Fidder

Tags: wcf, authentication, rest, fiddler, basic-authentication

I have created a WCF rest web service. However the client has requested the service be locked down with Basic Authentication but allow them to present the authorization token on first response rather than a challenge. Unfortunately I only have IIS 6 on my test machine

I only really need to simulate Basic Authentication so I doing this over anonymous and throwing an error if the Authorisation token is incorrect. However auth token is not available to the WCF

http://localhost/test.svc/get/token/

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Authorization: Basic Base64Value

If I remove anonymous and add basic in IIS. All's I get is a 401. Which I guess in IIS doing the authentication before the WCF.

Ideally I'd just like anoymous access and be able to access the authorization header.

How can I get the auth header

Comment: Do you want a way to read HTTP headers in your WCF Rest web service method?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption for this beeing an issue of IIS 6 is probably right.

I just created a WCF service "xxx.svc" and hosted it in the IIS (7.5), and when I requested it with fiddler2 with a correct Authorization header, it did not send a HTTP 401.

I will post my code so that you test it on IIS 6. If it still gives you HTTP 401, then this is surely an IIS 6 issue, if not try to compare and contrast your code with mine and see what configurations are different.

web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindConfig">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyTestSvc.MyService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/TestBasicAuth/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindConfig"
          name="webHttpBindingEndpoint" contract="MyTestSvc.IMyService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Service1.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyTestSvc.MyService" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyTestSvc
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate=@"/Hello")]
        string GetData();

    }
}
```

and finally: Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyTestSvc
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            WebOperationContext webCtx = WebOperationContext.Current; 
            IncomingWebRequestContext incomingCtx = webCtx.IncomingRequest; 
            string hdrVal = incomingCtx.Headers["Authorization"]; 

            return string.Format("Authorization: {0}", hdrVal);
        }
    }
}
```

fiddler Results:
[image: Fiddler Composer request]

[image: fiddler inspector, request/response raw]

Comment: This what I am doing. But the authorization header isn't there

Comment: And you have set **basic** as the authentication mode of the virtual directory hosting your WCF svc?

Comment: Yes I've now set basic, but when the basic is set the auth header is there but when it is a base64 string IIS steps in a causes a 401 before my code is hit.

Comment: This has to work on IIS. There are other IIS related things that we need to do. Could it be IIS6.